# Exclude list of file extensions from find in bash shell

Tags: linux, makefile, find

I want to write a cleanup routine for my make file that removes every thing except the necessary source files in my folder.  For example, my folder contains files with the following extensions: .f .f90 .F90 .F03 .o .h .out .dat .txt .hdf .gif.

I know I can accomplish this with:

```
find . -name \( '*.o' '*.out' '*.dat' '*.txt' '*.hdf' '*.gif' \) -delete
```

Using negation, I can do this:

```
find . -not -name '*.f*' -not -name '*.F*' -not -name '*.h' -delete
```

But, when I try to do this:

```
find . -not -name \( '*.f*' '*.F*' '*.h' \)
```

I get an error:

```
find: paths must exceed expression: [first expression in the above list]
```

(In this case, I would get: 
`find: paths must exceed expression: *.f*`
)

Can you explain why this happens, and how to do what I am trying to do?  I just hate writing -not -name every time I want to add a file extension to the list.  Also, I want to find out why this is giving me an error so that I can learn Linux better.

Thanks!

Comment: The first command `find . -name \( '*.o' '*.out' '*.dat' '*.txt' '*.hdf' '*.gif' \) -delete` should not be working, what makes you think it does?

Comment: Are there subdirectories you need to search as well?  Or is everything you want to clean kept in one directory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
find . -not -name \( '*.f' '*.F' '*.h' \)
```

is interpreted as

```
find
    .                      # path to search
    -not                   # negate next expression
    -name \(               # expression for files named "("
    '*.f' '*.F' .'*.h' \)  # more paths to search?
```

leading to the error.

Since these are single-letter extensions, you can collapse them to a single glob:

```
find . -not -name '*.[fFh]'
```

but if they are longer, you have to write out the globs

```
find . -not -name '*.f' -not -name '*.F' -not -name '*.h'
```

or

```
find . -not \( -name '*.f' -o -name '*.F' -o -name '*.h' \)
```

or switch to using regular expressions.

```
find . -not -regex '.*\.(f|F|h)$'
```

Note that regular expressions in `find` is not part of the POSIX standard and might not be available in all implementations.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: I tried this on Cygwin using find (GNU findutils) 4.9.0. On this version, the default regex type is emacs which requires escaping parentheses and pipe symbols (regex ORs). So for your last method, with regular expressions, I have to either specify an alternate regex type that supports those unescaped, e.g. `-regextype egrep`, or escape them, e.g. `'.*\.\(f\|F\|h\)$'`.